# grails 2.3.5 install JQuery Datatable 1.9.4 plugin to new project

Tags: grails, datatable

Grails plugin site has older version of jquery datatables plugin. I found 1.9.4 version from this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerydatatable/?source=dlp.

trying to install this to new project. install plugin command removed from new version of grails.

copied jquery-datatables-1.9.4.zip zip file to $HOME/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/jquery-datatables/zips

then ran the run-app, its not installing the plugin. What is the right way to install this plugin?

message from run-app command.

```
Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jquery-datatables:zip:1.9.4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jquery-datatables:zip:1.9.4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jquery-datatables:zip:1.9.4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:jquery-datatables:zip:1.9.4 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Thanks
-SR

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded to release plugin to latest version. and added  `legacyResolve true`
value to fix this error message.

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy file

```
 more grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy |egrep -v '^$|//'
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
        legacyResolve true
    inherits("global") {
    }
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
    plugins {
        build( ":tomcat:7.0.47",
              ":release:3.0.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
    }
}




 cat application.properties
#Grails Metadata file
#Mon Feb 03 22:55:28 GMT-05:00 2014
app.grails.version=2.3.5
app.name=jquery-datatables
app.servlet.version=2.5
plugins.jquery=1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugins should go into BuildConfig.groovy and not in the application.properties where the install plugin is adding them.

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

    // Added
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
}
```